# Use javascript code in php in function.php file

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I write this code for a login form in function.php file in Wordpress:

```
$name = $_POST['dx'];
$pass = $_POST['SX'];
$submitbutton= $_POST['commit'];
if ( isset($submitbutton) ) {
    if( isset($name) && empty($name) ){
        echo '<script> var errorMsg = document.getElementById("errorMsg");
        errorMsg.innerHTML = "username is empty";
        errorMsg.style.display = "block"; </script>';
    }
    else if( isset($pass) && empty($pass) ){
        $name = "";
        $pass = "";
        echo '<script> var errorMsg = document.getElementById("errorMsg");
        errorMsg.innerHTML = "password is empty";
        errorMsg.style.display = "block"; </script>';
    }
}
```

I got an error `Cannot read property 'style' of null`

- HTML code

```
<div class="login">
      <ul class="errorMessages" id="errorMsg">
          <li></li>
      </ul>
      <form method="post" action="">
          <p>
              <label for="dx">username</label><br>
              <input type="text" name="dx" value="" id="dx" maxlength="20">
          </p>
          <p>
              <label for="SX">password</label><br>
              <input id="SX" type="password" name="SX" value="" maxlength="30" 
              class="keyboardInput" vki_attached="true">
          </p>
          <div class="separator"></div>
          <p class="submit">
              <input type="submit" name="commit" value="login">
          </p>
      </form>
 </div>
```

I want to check the form fields, if fields were empty, show the error messege above the form.

[Something like this image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knlw1.png)

How can I use script code in right way in PHP? and how can I resolve this error?

Comment: does you HTML contains an element with id `errorMsg` ?

Comment: It would be better to echo the message (with its styles) directly from PHP.

Comment: @Nicolas Yes, HTML contains a `ul` element with that id

Comment: If html appears __after__ javascript code that refers to this html, obviously __javascript__ code will not work.

Comment: @Triby How can I do that? I want to display the message in style of the ``ul`` element that i define.

Comment: @farhikhteganweb, please edit your question adding the code where you show the message, so I can tell you how.

Comment: Are you just echoing it in functions.php? If so, then it will be echoed before any other code gets echoed. That would be invalid HTML. That won't stop it from working necessarily, but it is bad practice.

About your actual error: the issue is that the JS code is running before the errorMsg element exists. You should wrap your JavaScript in an event that will run after the HTML has all loaded:

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ /* put your alert stuff here */ });

Comment: @JosephOdom I changed my code to `echo '<script>document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ 
   var errorMsg = document.getElementById("errorMsg");errorMsg.innerHTML = "password is empty";errorMsg.style.display = "block";
   });</script>'; `
but I got that error again!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="login">
    <ul class="errorMessages" id="errorMsg">
    </ul>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <p>
            <label for="dx">username</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="dx" value="" id="dx" maxlength="20">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="SX">password</label><br>
            <input id="SX" type="password" name="SX" value="" maxlength="30" class="keyboardInput" vki_attached="true"><img src="http://account.taminm.ir/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/keyboard.png" alt="Display virtual keyboard interface" class="keyboardInputInitiator" title="Display virtual keyboard interface">
        </p>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" name="commit" value="login">
        </p>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const loginWrapper = document.querySelector('.login'),
        errorContainer = loginWrapper.querySelector('.errorMessages'),
        form = loginWrapper.querySelector('form');

    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const username = form.querySelector('#dx').value.trim(),
            password = form.querySelector('#SX').value.trim();
        if ( !username ) {
            errorContainer.innerHTML = 'username is empty';
        } else if (!password) {
            errorContainer.innerHTML = 'password is empty';
        } else {
            form.submit()
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I insert ``script`` with 'Insert Headers and Footers' plugin and I got 
``Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404`` error in source section of DevTools

Comment: I checked on a working site. All ok. Could it be the plugin?